# Does Spring integration provide any monitoring/time performance utility for its components?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

We use Spring integration in our project. I wanted to monitor how much time each integration component run is taking. I adopted AOP for this purpose, but with AOP I cannot uniquely identify the components running in parallel.

For ex: I've 4 objects in a queue, and 3 jms consumers running in parallel. Further, the consumer would put the message to a router etc

In the above scenario, I cannot uniquely identify the each component running time for a single object flow.

For this, is there a utility provided by Spring ? If not, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Spring-Actuator helps you. 
take a look at :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator

Otherwise you have to make your customized subscribers and providers. but by Spring-Actuator you can make your own too!

Comment: Also pay attention to the metrics functionality in Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metrics-management